# Python - if name shows up in a specific position in the directory path

Tags: python, if-statement, indexing, split, directory

I am trying to write a if statement for a directory path.
For example,

```
names = "Mary", "Joe", "John"
path = "C:/a/b/c/d/e"
```

If names shows up in specifically position d, then do sth.
What is the syntax that I can use?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if path.split("/")[4] in names:
```

You can try it like:

```
names = "Mary", "Joe", "John"
path = "C:/a/b/c/John/e"
print(path.split("/")[4] in names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this from a different angle implied by your example: if you're looking to detect the user, then you can use the `os` module:

```
import os
N = ['Mary','John','Foo']
U = os.path.expanduser('~')

print([NAME for NAME in N if(NAME in U)])
>>> Mary
```

That, of course, assumes that you're looking for usernames within user home directories, so this may not be relevant.

If it really is just an arbitrary path, then make your dir list a list check for the desired position (starting at 0):

```
import os
N = ['Mary','John','Foo']
P = ['a','b','c','Mary']

print([NAME for NAME in N if(NAME in U[3]) ])
>>> ['Mary']
```

Comment: The angle is good bit it should be a predicate, not a list... I mean, I will up vote if you edit and achieve that your function returns a boolean value, because I wants to use it in a if statement